# Eclipse not applying selection foreground color

Tags: eclipse, colors

I used http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ to set up syntax coloring in Eclipse.  My standard palette is dark on light, but selected text is inverted (light on dark).  The problem is that Eclipse uses my selection background color but keeps the regular foreground color, so I wind up with an unreadable dark-on-dark.

Generally this is on code, so my foreground colors are coming from the syntax-based colors, but I tried this on a plain text file that uses the basic colors from the General > Editors > Text Editors preference.  Normal text is "Foreground color" on "Background color" and selected text is "Foreground color" on "Selection background color" -- it seems to ignore "Selection foreground color" entirely.

This is Eclipse Indigo on OS X.  I recently swapped hardware and went through a long and iterative process of rebuilding my Eclipse environment, but I could swear that this was working fine previously (on Helios).

Comment: Answering my own question, this looks like a bug in the OS X SWT library; it doesn't honor the background color settings. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371924

Comment: Using Kubuntu here... same problem, any ideas/sources for a fix? 
Both Eclipse 3.7 and 4.2 open up with code black on almost black background after installation, quite a downer for starters ;)

Comment: Same problem here with Eclipse 4.4 on Windows, restarting Eclipse didn't work

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is using the plain text editor for that file? Check it with _Right click inside the editor view > Preferences..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an earlier answer as a comment, so here it is as an answer.

This is defined in the OS X SWT library, it deliberately ignores the configured "Selection foreground color":

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371924

This comment on the Eclipse ticket pointed to the workaround I'm using:

> [On the Mac] the typical scheme is to have a selection background color that is close to the non-selection background color.

The workaround is **don't use an inverted color scheme for selection**. The native Mac UI indicates selection by subtly shading the background color, without changing the foreground color, so the SWT library is enforcing this UI pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having issues with 'selection color' on a dark background. I was interested in changing 'selection background color' and not foreground color though.

A restart of Eclipse worked for me on OS X (other color changes take effect immediately, but 'selection background color' wasn't taking effect until I restarted Eclipse)

I also upgraded to latest version of Eclipse before doing that.